# Catch without try

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a problem when i execute this servlet in cmd it show me  error: 'catch' 
without 'try'
     catch (XQException e) {

I will be very grateful if you find the error in my servlet

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException{
try  {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();  
        XQDataSource ds = new SaxonXQDataSource();
        XQConnection conn = ds.getConnection();                      
    String xqueryRequest="for $t in doc('/WEB- 
    INF/theatre.xml')/theatres/theatre"+
    "order by $t/nom"+
    "return"+
    "<theatres>"+
    "<theatre>"+
    "{$t/nom}"+
    "{$t/adresse}"+
    "</theatre>"+
    "</theatres>";
  InputStream xsl = (InputStream)(context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB- 
  INF/theatre.xsl"));
        Source xslDoc3 =  new StreamSource(xsl);

      XQPreparedExpression exp = conn.prepareExpression(xqueryRequest);  
        XQResultSequence result = exp.executeQuery(); 

        while (result.next()) {  
            out.println(result.getItemAsString(null));  
        }   

    StringWriter swr3 = new StringWriter();
    out.println(swr3.toString());
    out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex1){
    ex1.printStackTrace();
    }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
      finally{
    catch (XQException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 
      }

}
}
```

so, can you help me plase? and thanks to all of you.

Comment: You have a `catch` inside your `finally`.

Comment: have a look at your `finally` block - it has a `catch(...)` without a `try` (just like the error messages says)

Comment: when i take off "finally" it show 2 erros theatre.java:66: error: exception FileNotFoundException has already been caught
                 catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 ^
theatre.java:70: error: exception XQException has already been caught
        catch (XQException e) {

Comment: You're also catching `FileNotFoundException` and `XQException` **after** catching `Exception`, which is a superclass of them both, so they are both unreachable.

Comment: But i can't make a new post to ask a new question for my second problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: the catch in your finally block is not coming after a try!

It doesn't matter that there was a try before the finally here! The finally keyword "ends" the list of catch blocks belonging to the initial try statement. Thus the catch in that finally block is an "orphan", it lacks a previous try.

Comment: but when i take of the finally it's show me 2 errors:                                theatre.java:66: error: exception FileNotFoundException has already been caught
                 catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 ^
theatre.java:70: error: exception XQException has already been caught
        catch (XQException e) {

Comment: @mrinfo remove the first `catch(Exception ex1)`.

Comment: thank you so much I managed to generate the .class of the servlet but there is another problem: i got an empty page in the navigateur :/